# Tweening across a fixed L shaped path with MotionGuide plugin

Tags: javascript, animation, tween, createjs

I am diving into Tween.js for some elementary animation.

It seems like for making a ball move across a fixed path you need the MotionGuide plugin. Here is a document at :

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/classes/MotionGuidePlugin.html

I want to make my object move in a sort of an inverted L shaped maze, how do I change the array values in the supplied path object? The values as the documents imply are translating to moveTo and curveTo calls.

I am not sure as to how to make it traverse a fixed L shaped path. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code of the Plugin, it just seems to be able to use `curveTo` with a single `moveTo` at the start, but you can also do straight lines with that but positioning the anchor-points in the middle between two points - However, in your case you could(and that's how I would do it) use the regular tween `.to()` and just chain the calls to each corner if the path has only straight lines and hard corners.